# Interchange a raw value in Doctrine 2 result

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, doctrine-orm

#### The Problem:

I am working on a WordPress Symfony bundle and creating entities for it.

I have a `Comment` entity, and `$comment->user` is mapped to an `User` entity.

However **WordPress use `0` to represent a guest user**. It cause a lots of problems in Doctrine because the user with id zero never exist. It cause the following issues:

- `$comment->getUser()` might throw an entity not found exception when the row's `user_id` is `0`.
- `$comment->setUser()` doesn't work because you can not use `null` to repensent guest (should use `0`), and you cannot use `new User(0)` neither.

#### The Question:

By default, the following code would save `null` to `user_id` column in database:

```
$comment->setUser(null);
```

Is it possible to make Doctrine save `0` (instead of `null`) to the `user_id` column?

Or even better, can I interchange `0` and `null` when dealing with the `user_id` column?

Thank you for your time.

#### Test Cases:

```
// if a guest posted a comment, pass null to setUser()
// although the actual value will be saved to user_id column is 0
$guestComment->setUser(null);

// if a comment was posted by a guest, getUser() should return null
// although the actual value returned by user_id column is 0
$guestComment->getUser(); // return null

// if a member posted a comment, pass a User entity to setUser()
$memberComment->setUser(new User());

// if a comment was posted by a member, getUser() should return the User entity
$guestComment->getUser(); // return User entity.
```

#### Direction:

I am looking at creating a custom mapping types
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/types.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I turn out fixed the problem by creating a custom type:

https://github.com/kayue/WordpressBundle/blob/master/Types/WordPressIdType.php

```
<?php

/**
 * Datatype for WordPress's IDs
 *
 * WordPress use 0 to represent a guest user. It cause a lots of problems
 * in Doctrine because the user with id zero never exist. This datatype
 * convert 0 to null, make life easier.
 */

namespace Hypebeast\WordpressBundle\Types;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Types\BigIntType;
use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;

class WordPressIdType extends BigIntType
{
    const NAME = 'wordpressid';

    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        if($value === 0) {
            return null;
        }

        return $value;
    }

    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        if($value === null) {
            return 0;
        }

        return $value;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return self::NAME;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it's very simple.

Just replace your `setUser` function with one which converts a 0 into a null, and replace your `getUser` function with one which converts a null into a 0.

```
public function setUser($user) {
    if($user == 0) {
        $user = null;
    }

    $this->user = $user;
}

public function getUser() {
    return $this->user == null ? 0 : $this->user;
}
```

Doctrine 2 doesn't limit you in any way with regards to what your getters and setters can do. (or any methods in your entities for that matter)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but your method always return `0` when user is a "guest". What I want is `getUser()` method should still return `null` to my application, at the mean time it should return `0` to database.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Why does it need to save a 0 to the database? If it was by a guest, there is no user, thus a null value should be stored in the DB (the relation does not exist). How is this a problem to your program code?

Comment: Yes `null` should be stored in the DB, but this is not how WordPress work, and I cannot fix it because it is WordPress. So this is actually WordPress's design problem, and cause me trouble.

Comment: @kayue ah so is the User entity actually a representation of the WordPress user table? And if you were to store a null in the field, it would break WordPress?

Comment: Yes, User entity is mapping to WordPress's user table. We are using WordPress and Symfony at the same time, thus WordPress will keep generate these problematic records (this is not the only one!). There is no data integrity concept in WordPress at all :(

Comment: @kayue Yeah now I understand :) Yeah WP is kind of.. ugh. The solution you found is probably the best option.